# Icons in System Tray in Taskbars mirrored by DisplayFusion

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, displayfusion

How can I configure DisplayFusion so that the Windows Taskbars on the non-primary monitors have the same number of rows for the icons in the System Tray than on Windows Taskbar on the primary monitor?

I use DisplayFusion 5.0.1 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

---

Example:

I have a few monitors connected to my computer. I use DisplayFusion with the multi-monitor taskbar feature enabled.

The Windows Taskbar on the primary monitor contains *4 rows*:

[image]

The Windows Taskbar mirrors on the other monitors contains *3 rows*:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to configure DisplayFusion so that the Windows Taskbars on the non-primary monitors have the same number of rows for the icons in the System Tray than on Windows Taskbar on the primary monitor.